# Is it actually possible to use any Computer Algebra System (CAS) in R?

Tags: python, r, math, sympy

I was searching for some way to use **Sympy** in R, but I didn't find anything that could solve the equation below without errors.

[image: Equation]

Is is actually possible to use something like Sympy in R?

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/05/caracas-computer-algebra-in-r-via-sympy/

Comment: There is a package [rSymPy](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rSymPy) on CRAN.

Comment: Do you need the symbolic solution or a numeric one will do?

Comment: A numeric one should work.

Comment: @MartinGal I tried this, but it didn't work for this equation... I don't know what to do

Comment: Felipe, you were saying a numerical solution is okay. If so, take a look at the function `uniroot`. I think there are probably others. Also, if you need the result in R, maybe it's easiest to just get a solution using some other system and copy the result back to R.

Comment: Over in the python-sympy world we like to see the actual error messages, not some sort of generic 'without errors'.  Is is a problem with using `sympy` in `R`, or a problem that `sympy` has with this particular equation?  I suppose I could try solving it using `sympy` in `python`, but you don't show enough code to start.

Answer (score 3):

There are several packages at CRAN that may help:

- [Ryacas](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Ryacas) interfacing yacas
- its predecessor [Ryacas0](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ryacas0/index.html)
- [rim](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rim/index.html) interfacing maxima
- [caracas](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rim/index.html) interfacing sympy

They may all have different levels of difficulty in terms installing the underlying 'engine' but this should get you started.

Comment: I tried Ryacas and caracas. Both didn't work, and rSymPy is not available anymore (as I know)

Comment: You are correct, rSymPy is archived.  As for what you tried: such context can help in asking the question because we then have a better idea of what you tried or didn''t try. There is also Wolfram Alpha with its web interface...

Comment: can you show us what you tried/what problems you got with Ryacas and caracas?

Answer (score 1):

It will definitely be easiest to do this numerically, if you can live with that:

```r
uniroot(function(x) 1000/(1+x)^(25/252) - 985, c(0,10))
```

However: I tried this in Wolfram Alpha, which gave me the exact result

```
x = (102400000000000000000000 2^(6/25) 5^(4/25) 197^(23/25) - 
     17343170265605241347130653)/17343170265605241347130653
```

and then moments later reverted to giving me the numerical approximation (x ≈ 0.164562) -- I had to quickly copy the text before it disappeared.

When I tried this with `sympy`, it quickly gave me a numerical answer:

```py
from sympy import *
x = Symbol("x")
solve(1000/((1+x)**(25/252)) - 985, x)
[0.164562487329317]
```

... but trying to get an exact solution by setting `numerical = False` was no good: it seemed to have to work fairly hard (pegged CPU at 100% for several minutes before I gave up).  This is consistent with my results from `Ryacas`,

```r
library(Ryacas)
yac("Solve(1000/((1+x)^(25/252)) == 985, x)")
```

> Error in yac_core(x) :
> Yacas returned this error: CommandLine(1) : Max evaluation stack depth reached.
> Please use MaxEvalDepth to increase the stack size as needed.

However, there is a surprising shortcut. The hard part of this problem is actually doing the deep recursion needed to unravel the (25/252) power exactly. If you're happy with a *more general* solution, you can get it quickly:

In `sympy`:

```py
a = Symbol("a")
solve(1000/((1+x)**(a)) - 985, x, numerical = False)
[-1 + 200**(1/a)/197**(1/a)]
```

For what it's worth, this looks simpler (to a human) as `-1 + (200/197)**(1/a)` (there's probably some simplification setting that would convince `sympy` to do this but ...)

This works in `caracas` (an R wrapper for `sympy`) too, once everything is set up:

```r
library(caracas)
x <- symbol('x')
a <- symbol('a')
solve_sys(1000/((1+x)^a), 985, list(x))
## Solution 1:
##   x =          -1         
##               ───        
##                a  a _____
##       -1 + 197   ⋅╲╱ 200
```

Unfortunately, the same trick doesn't seem to work for Ryacas.